# How to change Linux terminal prompt

Tags: linux, command-line, terminal, prompt

I've been using Terminator as my terminal but after reconfiguring my display manager to 'Lightdm' after 'gdm3' crashed while installing updates, I messed something up, not with terminal, using the GUI and changed my terminal prompts to windows style ie `C:\home\myusername\pwd>` when I do `echo $PS1` it returns `C:${PWD//\//\}>`. I've tried commenting `PS1="C:${PWD//\//\}>` in the **.bashrc** but nothing is changing even after rebooting.

Comment: ... why? Just why? A windows style prompt with a leading `C:` makes zero sense

Comment: I too don't understand why... Everything looks like windows, even the 'open' dialog interfaces and 'save' dialogs